# Word Export ASP.NET MVC Beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to ASP.NET MVC and tried to generate an export from Formdata to word file. That worked quite well, all the Bookmarks in the Document are filled correctly with following code:

```
string savePath = (@"U:\Coding ASP.MVC\WebForm Export into WordFile\Gutachten.docx");
string templatePath = (@"U:\Coding ASP.MVC\WebForm Export into WordFile\wordTemplate.docx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
doc = app.Documents.Open(templatePath);
doc.Activate();

if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("FileNoSIS"))
{
    doc.Bookmarks["FileNoSIS"].Range.Text = FileNoSIS;
}

if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("NameOfAction"))
{
    doc.Bookmarks["NameOfAction"].Range.Text = NameOfAction;
}

doc.SaveAs2(savePath);
app.Application.Quit();
Response.Write("Success");
```

But now i want to get the thing done with a stream to edit the document and offer the new filled document as a download. Can anybody here give me some advice or any tip how to get there?

Thx